# Reemplazar datos de una columna en un data frame tomando datos de otro data frame en base a condiciones- R

Tags: r

Estoy con una duda que no puedo resolver, y quizá alguien puede ayudarme.

Tengo un data frame que tiene dos columnas con ID(ID1 e ID2) por asi decirlo y otra con valores. Por el otro, tengo otro data frame con la misma configuracion, solo que para determinados ID, tiene distintos valores en la columna VALUE1.  Lo que estoy intentando es lo siguiente: Mi idea es armar un tercer DF, el cual cuando ID1 e ID2 cumplan ciertos criterios, tome los valores del DF2. En resumidas cuentas seria alguna especie de IF en el DF que cuando ID1 e ID2 cumplan una condicion "x" tomen los valores de la columna values del DF2, de lo contrario, que mantengan el dato que figura en el DF1.

Adjunto un ejemplo, donde tengo 3 data frames. La idea seria que tome el DF1 como base, pero que si el ID1=5 y el ID2<100, entonces reemplace los valores de la columna VALUE1, en base a los datos del DF2. El DF3 seria el resultado buscado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente utilizar if, ifelse y merge pero no obtuve los resultados que esperaba. Alguien podria orientarme?

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar necesitas relacionar las filas de los dos `data.frames` (join) por ambos `ID` y luego usar un `VALUE` en función de la condición del `ID2 < 100`. Esto si puedes usar `tidyverse` es bastantes simple:

Suponiendo estos datos:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID1=c(5, 5), ID2=c(50, 150), VALUE1=c(100, 100))
df2 <- data.frame(ID1=c(5, 5), ID2=c(50, 150), VALUE1=c(40, 30))
```

Podemos hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("ID1", "ID2")) %>% 
  mutate(VALUE = ifelse(ID2 < 100 & !is.na(VALUE1.y), VALUE1.y, VALUE1.x)) %>% 
  select(ID1, ID2, VALUE)

  ID1 ID2 VALUE
1   5  50    40
2   5 150   100
```

El `left_join()` relaciona las filas según `by` y el `mutate()` lo usamos para crear la nueva columna `VALUE` que es el resultado de la condición en el `ifelse()`.

Eventualmente, podrías usar R base aunque, en estos casos, suele ser un código menos claro o explicativo:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("ID1", "ID2"), all.x = TRUE)
df3$VALUE <- ifelse(df3$ID2 < 100 & !is.na(df3$VALUE1.y), df3$VALUE1.y, df3$VALUE1.x)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Creo que entiendo y ya mismo lo voy chequear. No queria dejar de preguntarte(quiza es una pregunta facil de chequear en otro lado pero aun no lo encontre) ¿ Que función cumple la parte del codigo _& !is.na(df3$VALUE1.y), df3$VALUE1.y, df3$VALUE1.x)_ 

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por lo que has mostrado en tu ejemplo, no todos los IDs de df1 se encuentran en df2, ese código es para validar que si vas a usar `df2$VALUE1` este no sea `NA` por que no existe la fila en df2.

Comment: Perdon, lo copie mal.  Seria la siguiente parte  _df3$VALUE1.y, df3$VALUE1.x)_ entiendo que seria el resultado que arroja el ifelse cuando no se cumplen las condiciones, pero no entiendo porque figura una vez con .y, y luego con .x.  De nuevo,mil gracias!

Comment: Ok, cuando se hace un merge o join de dos dataframes las columnas con el mismo nombre se renombran como nombre.y y nombre .y una es la del df1 y la otra la del df2